# Почему edittext перехватывает событие нажатия root элемента?

Tags: android

Пишу кастомною вьюшку ввода смс пинкода. Вьюшка содержит 6 элементов editText. Хочу поставить слушатель на root элемент вьюшки. Он работает, но только если нажать на промежуток между edit text. Если нажать на один из edit text - открывается клавиатура, но слушатель не отрабатывает. Почему так происходит?

Comment: Потому что EditText отрабатывает нажатия и дальше их не передает. Но это поведение можно менять. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events#EventHandlers

Comment: Вот тут еще несколько альтернатив: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415528/how-to-pass-a-views-onclick-event-to-its-parent-on-android

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415528/how-to-pass-a-views-onclick-event-to-its-parent-on-android